# How to combine two hashes with same keys into a 2D array in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have two hashes of values by date:

```
 a = {1=>4, 2=>5, 3=>10}
 b = {1=>43, 2=>25, 3=>28}
```

How would I combine them in Ruby into a 2D array like this:

```
 c = [[1, 4, 43], [2, 5, 25], [3, 10, 28]]
```

Comment: Please read "[ask]" including the linked pages, "[mcve]" and "[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)". We'd like to see evidence of your effort. What did you try? Did you search and not find anything? Did you find stuff but it didn't help? Did you try writing code? If not, why? If so, what is the smallest code example that shows what you tried and why didn't it work? Without that it looks like you didn't try and want us to write it for you.

Comment: Thanks for feedback Tin Man, I did have some code but I thought it would be clutter given how simple I'm sure it would be in ruby. Lots of hash.to_a.transpose involved in my attempt.

Comment: It's important to understand that SO isn't a "help me with my code problem" site, instead it's a "here's how to solve this problem with code" site for other people who run into it in the future. As such it's important to document the problem then show the minimal code necessary to demonstrate the problem. We want to see your effort because it helps others understand your process, short-circuits the "didja try this?" chain, and helps us help you find a solution more quickly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `Enumerable#map`:

```
a.map { |k, v| [k, v, b[k]] }
#=> [[1, 4, 43], [2, 5, 25], [3, 10, 28]]
```

Or, if you have different keys in your hashes, use `Hash#merge`:

```
a.merge(b) { |_, o, n| [o, n] }.map { |k, v| [k, *v] }
#=> [[1, 4, 43], [2, 5, 25], [3, 10, 28]]
```